# JavaScript Mouse position over an element (code not working)

Tags: mouse, position

I want to display the mouse position when its inside an element.. heres the code:

```
Mouse Events Example


 function GetMousePositionInElement(ev, element)
           {
               var osx = element.offsetX;
               var osy = element.offsetY;

               var bottom = osy + element.height();

               var x = ev.pageX - osx;
               var y = bottom - ev.pageY;

               return { x: x, y: y, y_fromTop: element.height() - y };
           }
    function handleEvent(oEvent) {
        var oTextbox = document.getElementById("txt1");
        var elem = document.getElementById("div1");
        var xp = GetMousePositionInElement(oEvent, elem).x;
        var yp = GetMousePositionInElement(oEvent, elem).y; 

        oTextbox.value += "\n x = " + xp + "y= " + yp;

    }



 Use your mouse to click and double click the red square.
div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red"
     onmouseover="handleEvent(event)"
     id="div1"> /div
 textarea id="txt1" rows="15" cols="50"> /textarea>
```

There is a problem in the code. Mouse position is not displayed inside the texArea. What changes do i have to make for the code to work and work correctly? (of-cource not all of the code is displayed and i removed some of the < and > inoder to show you some parts of the code that are not displayed otherwise but the code syntax is correct, thats not the problem)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> var osy = element.offsetY;

There's no such property as `offsetY`. You may be thinking of `offsetTop`. However note the `offsetLeft`/​`Top` values are relative to the `offsetParent` not the page. If you want page-relative co-ordinates you would need to loop through offsetParents, or, since you seem to be including jQuery, call its [offset](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) function that does just that:

```
var offset= $(element).offset();
var osx= offset[0], osy= offset[1];
```

> var bottom = osy + element.height();

`element` is a DOM HTMLDivElement object, not a jQuery wrapper object, so it doesn't have the `height()` method. Either add the wrapper:

```
var bottom= osy+$(element).height();
```

or use the equivalent DOM method:

```
var bottom= osy+element.offsetHeight;
```

> var y = bottom - ev.pageY;

Note `pageY` is not part of the DOM Events standard and also not available in IE. You can calculate it by using the standard `clientY` property and adjusting for the page's `scrollTop`. Again, jQuery does this for you, adding the Firefox `pageY` extension to all browsers, when you use its own methods to bind your event handler:

```
$('#div1').mouseover(handleEvent);
```

instead of the inline `onmouseover=...` event handler attribute.